# How to remove '~' sub-directory in .vscode on Ubuntu (Pop!_OS) 19.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I was messing with VS Code trying to get an extension to work.  I kept getting a message that I needed to run VS Code as root in order to get the config file to save.  Now I have this strange dir in my **.vscode** directory.

```
╰─ ls -al                                                                         
total 24
drwxrwxr-x  4 awag awag 4096 Mar  6 21:37  .
drwxr-xr-x 45 awag awag 4096 Mar  6 22:06  ..
drwx------  4 root root     4096 Mar  6 21:38 '~'
-rw-rw-r--  1 awag awag  695 Mar  1 12:05  argv.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 awag awag   48 Mar  6 21:36  custom.css
drwxrwxr-x 37 awag awag 4096 Mar  6 21:55  extensions

╰─ sudo rmdir \~                                                                  
rmdir: failed to remove '~': Directory not empty
```

It looks like the '~' file is pointing to ~, and I can't figure out how to remove that subdirectory in .vscode

Any ideas on how to get rid of it without trashing the real ~ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command will do it:

```sh
rm -rf "~"
```

from inside `.vscode`.

If you want to check before you try it, try:

```sh
echo ~
# OUTPUT: /home/username

echo "~"
# OUTPUT: ~
```